# No request to /oauth/token after receiving authorization code

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, access-token, oauth-2.0

Currently using @EnableOAuth2Sso in spring boot 1.4 and on receiving authorization code on redirect url ie

http://someip:port/?code=9tttttttt2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

there is no request for access token on /oauth/token.

OAuth2AccessToken is null when requested from OAuth2ClientContext on call of redirect uri with authorization code.

No request to /oauth/token after receiving authorization code from a thrid party authorization server. How can i debug or should i make a explicit request for token using a rest template?